# Mantener opcion de un Select luego de un post en JSP y Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, jstl

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectTransporte" >
       <option >Seleccione Transporte</option> 
       <c:forEach items="${listadoTransporte}" var="lista">
          <option value="${lista.getId()}">${lista.getNombre()}       </option>
       </c:forEach>
       <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="idTransporte" name="idTransporte" value="" />
</select>
```

Les dejo mi consulta para ver si me dan una mano. Estoy desarrollando un sistema en `Spring MVC`.

Hace algún tiempo que desarrollo en JAVA, pero esta vez estoy atrapado en un formulario que contiene un `<select>` con varias opciones (para el caso el contenido da igual), el cual envía por `POST` al `controller` los datos, el `controller` retorna un listado en el mismo formulario, pero esto causa que el valor seleccionado en el `<select>` cambie al valor por default.

```
<select name="transporte">
    <option value=0>Seleccione Transporte</option>
    <option value=1>Coche</option>
    <option value=2>Avión</option>
    <option value=3>Tren</option>
</select>
```

Si selecciono avión, muestra una lista de los modelos de avión, a modo de ejemplo.

Como puedo mantener el valor que envié por `POST` desde el `JSP` al momento de recargar la página con el listado, o como puedo reasignar la selección anterior?

He probado pasando el id del `<option>` a un `<input type="text>` y luego tomando este valor por `JS` para pasarlo al `<select>` en `JQuery` así:

```
$("#transporte option[value="+ $("#txtTransporte").val() +"]").attr("selected",true);
```

Pero el `<select>` regresa a "Seleccione Transporte".

Desde ya gracias.-

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el ejemplo de como pintas este `select` en el `JSP`?. Supongo que el `select` que has puesto de ejemplo es como se vería en el `DOM`. Lo digo por que si pintas el `select` de manera dinámica con `Java` o `Jstl` la solución puede ser mejor que crear un `input` auxiliar. Aun así es valida la solución, del `input` por lo que algo debes de estar haciendo mal al pintar el valor en el `input`. Te recomiendo poner un ejemplo mas completo, añadir la forma de pintar el `select` y el `input` a la pregunta.

Comment: @x3k_js como lo indicaste agregue el select cuando lo estoy llenando.

Answer (score 1):

Para pintar el `<select>` con la `<option>` seleccionada puedes usar un operador ternario:

```
${transporteVar != null ? 'selected' : ''}
```

`transporteVar` sería la variable que usas  en el `value` del `<input>` con id `txtTransporte` (No se como se llama la variable ya que no esta en la pregunta, es un ejemplo).

También decir que yo lo comparo con `null` ya que no se la lógica que usas en la variable esta. Pero si lo que envías es el id del transporte que se selecciono solo tendrías que comparar el `value` de esa `option` con la variable:

```
${transporteVar == lista.getId() ? 'selected' : ''}
```

El ejemplo completo en la `<option>`:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectTransporte" >
   <option>Seleccione Transporte</option> 
   <c:forEach items="${listadoTransporte}" var="lista">
      <option value="${lista.getId()}" ${transporteVar != null ? 'selected' : ''}>${lista.getNombre()}       </option>
   </c:forEach>
   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="idTransporte" name="idTransporte" value="" />
</select>
```